# To read JSON files faster from AWS S3 using PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, pyspark-transformer

I have written a PySpark code in AWS Glue ETL where I need to read multiple small (`2KB`) JSON files from the AWS S3 path. S3 has a bucket, prefix, and then partition keys. Partitions like `accountid`, `region`, and `type`. So, for the S3 path, I am using a wild card search as follows:

```py
path = 'S3://bucket//accountid=*/region=*/type=/*.json'
```

And to read:

```py
df = spark.read.json(path).select(selected_columns).dropDuplicates()
```

But it is taking too much time to read all the data, an hour. How can I read this data quickly within a few minutes or seconds? I tried using custom schema also but it is not helping much. Please help.

Comment: Path = 'S3://bucket//accountid=*/region=*/type=/*.json'.